# How to group data per week in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

```
id     modid    userid  timemodified FROM_UNIXTIME(timemodified,'%d-%m-%Y')     
410     32       46      1438971403     03-08-2015
411     32       46      1438971403     03-08-2015
412     66       977     1438971403     07-08-2015
412     66       977     1438971403     07-08-2015
413     67       34      1438971423     07-08-2015
414     68       16      1438971424     07-08-2015
415     132      23      1438972154     07-08-2015
416     134       2      1438972465     08-08-2015
417     115       2      1438996430     08-08-2015
418     130      977     1438996869     08-08-2015
```

I got this query from framing the last 4weeks ago by calculating from today's date. Now, I want to show the users for 4 weeks individually like week1, week2, week3 & week4, either it could be column wise or row wise, which would be the best.

```
In detailed, from the above query, I need to separate data from week1 to week4,like

              Week4 : No user
              Week3 : 2 users (2,977)
              Week2 : 4 users (16, 23, 34, 977)
              Week1 : 1 user (46)

 SET @unix_four_weeks_ago = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(curdate()) - 2419200;  

 SELECT *,FROM_UNIXTIME(timemodified,'%d-%m-%Y') FROM mod_users WHERE timemodified >= @unix_four_weeks_ago
```

Comment: Your question might be obvious to you but I really don't what you are trying to accomplish here. Can you break it down even more ?  Explain the situation and what is that data.

Comment: Maxime - I need to separate week1 to week4 data.

Comment: Between 03/08 and 08/08, there is only 5 days. How come your data is split across 3 weeks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you want to split the user count per week according to the `timemodified` column.  I would use the [`WEEK()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) function to do that.

The following SQL would add a `weeknumber` column to identify the week number:

```
SELECT WEEK(timemodified) weeknumber, dates.* 
FROM dates
```

Then, if you want to get the distinct user count, you can simply use the following SQL:

```
SELECT WEEK(timemodified) weeknumber, COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) users_count
FROM dates
GROUP BY weeknumber
```

You can also add a `WHERE` clause to get only certain weeks as you wish.  So, to get the last 4 weeks from the 23-08-2015, I would do:

```
SELECT WEEK(timemodified) weeknumber, COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) users_count
FROM dates
WHERE WEEK(timemodified) <= WEEK('2015-08-23') 
    AND WEEK(timemodified) > (WEEK('2015-08-23') - 4)
GROUP BY weeknumber
```

Let's hope I assumed correctly. :-)

Comment: Maxime - I wasn't getting the week number it shows NULL